# How to get time without timezone?

Tags: go, time

I'm converting unix timestamp to time

```
newTime := time.Unix(int64(1537957097), 0)
```

and it retrns time with a timezone - 2017-10-12T19:10:56+05:00

how can i remove time zone from it?

format i want to get - 2017-10-12T19:10:56

Comment: What good is a time without the timezone?  Without the timezone, the time you obtain is ambiguous.

Comment: Simply call `newTime.UTC()`. It returns the new time, you may want to store it, e.g. `newTime = newTime.UTC()`.

Comment: or you can format the time using time.Parse according to the format you want.

Comment: @AndrewHenle my program is used only in one time zone, so i want only get time,without timezone.

Comment: @icza converts time, after `.UTC()` i got my time minus 5 hours

Comment: Then it looks you **do** want it in local timezone, you just don't want to print the zone info. Then use your intended format, and print it with `time.Format()`.

Comment: @icza yes, thank you